# ServiceStack: how to change member attributes in the API model at service startup?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, servicestack

We use ServiceStack for our Web APIs developed in C#. I would like to change the required attribute of our data members at the moment the web service starts.

Currently the required attribute is defined that way at compile time:

```
[ApiMember(IsRequired=true)]
public string MyAttribute { get; set; }
```

I would like to define its value 'dynamically' when executing the AppHost.Configure.

Is there a way to achieve this with ServiceStack ? In the same manner we define routes with the Fluent api (for example: `Routes.Add<HOPFlight>("/flight", "POST");` ) ?

I read the answer [Dynamically adding attributes in ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403300/dynamically-adding-attributes-in-servicestack) that suggests to do it in the AppHost Constructor but how to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you linked provides an example in the original question.  Note that if you try to add this in the Configure function of your AppHost it is probably too late.  You should add it in the constructor of the AppHost.  From your linked question, mythz says

> For dynamically adding Service Attributes you need to add them before
>   AppHost.Configure() since they're already initialized by the time
>   Configure() is run, so they need to be either added in AppHost
>   constructor or before AppHost.Init() is called.

In your case, something like this should work,

```
public AppHost(string serviceName, Assembly[] serviceAssemblies) : base(serviceName, serviceAssemblies)
{
    ApiMemberAttribute requiredAttribute = new ApiMemberAttribute {
        IsRequired = true
    } 

    Type[] requiredApiMembers = GetTypesToAddApiMemberAttributeTo();  //do whatever you need to get the types you want to add attributes to
    foreach(requiredApiMember in requiredApiMembers)
    {
      requiredApiMember.AddAttributes(requiredAttribute);
    }
}
```